# design pattern to bind JAXB to domain object and vice versa

Tags: java, design-patterns, jaxb

We have multiple RESTful services that would need object mapping between JAXB to domain objects and vice versa.

I was thinking to define an common interface similar to the following.
//mapper interface

```
   public interface Mapper{
       Object toDomainObject(Object jaxb);
       Object toClientObject(Object domain);
    }
```

// RecorderMapper class - implements Mapper interface

```
public class RecorderMapper implements Mapper{
            @Override
        public Object toDomainObject(Object obj) {
            JAXBRecorderRequest jAXBRecorderRequest = (JAXBRecorderRequest)obj;
            RecorderDomain recorderDomain = new RecorderDomain();
            //map to jaxb to domain
            return recorderDomain;
        }

        @Override
public Object toClientObject(Object obj) {
    RecorderDomain recorderDomain = (RecorderDomain)obj;
    JAXBRecorderResponse jaxbRecorderResponse = new JAXBRecorderResponse();
    //map domain to jaxb
    return jaxbRecorderResponse;
}
}
```

//Recorder service class - uses the Mapper for object mapping

```
public class Recorder Service {
    @Autowired
    private Mapper mapper;
    public JAXBRecorderResponse create(JAXBRecorderRequest jaxbRecorderRequest){
        RecorderDomain recorderDomain =(RecorderDomain) mapper.toDomainObject(jaxbRequest);
        return (JAXBRecorderResponse)mapper.toClientObject(recorderDomain);

    }
}
```

The main idea is to define a common pattern to implement object mapping across the team.

I wonder if there is a better way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/xmlbeans.html) for mapping.